# printf integer displays more than C++ cout

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I'm a C programmer picking up C++

Seems cout is a bit clunky, I don't understand why it produces a different output.

```
//The printf below displays value 50
//The cout below display value 2

data_to_send.data[2] = atoi(data_str.c_str());    
printf("\n DEBUG: %d\n",data_to_send.data[2]);
std::cout << "Debug: " << std::dec << data_to_send.data[2];
```

Comment: What is `data_to_send.data[2]`?

Comment: insufficient information.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on [ideone](https://ideone.com/AstlUs).

Comment: Insufficient information.  Without knowing the types or values  of `data_to_send.data` or `data_str` nobody can guess what the output of the code should be.  At the least, provide an [mcve] and an explanation of types and values.

Comment: Change `%d` to `%c` or `data_to_send.data[2]` to `(int)data_to_send.data[2]`.

Comment: Your question should have some [MCVE]. BTW `printf` is a C function (not a genuine C++ one).

Comment: Even though the question is interesting, I downvoted because you didn't provide enough details (declarations).

Answer (score 2):

Your `data_to_send.data[2]` field is a `char` or `unsigned char type` (byte).

`printf` sees it as the integer `50`, as requested by the format specifier `%d`.

`cout` sees it as the character `'2'`, of ASCII code `50`, as implictly requested by the data type.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `data_to_send.data` is `char*`, so `data_to_send.data[2]` is char with value `50`. When you call `printf` you specify to treat your argument as integer (`%d`) so it prints `50`. In C++ `cout` uses function overloading to call concrete function to concrete type of argument, in this case `operator<<` for `char`. ASCII value of `'2'` is `50`, thats why `2` is printed out.